# store Multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this inner join query then retrieve this data via loop then to store to ARRAY using PHP.(see image below)

[image]

AS you can see image above. it has 3 columns, I want to group it by `WOKRORDER` then by `DateField`:(see image below for expected output)

[image]

but here's the console.log of the result.I pass it to Jquery as JSON to see in console.log if my array storing is working.(see image below)

[image]

How can I do that in PHP Array?

here's my php array storing code so far:

```
$ListOfWorkOrderDates[$rowInnerJoin['WorkOrder']]=array(
                        $rowInnerJoin['DateField'] => array
                        (
                        'DatePosted' => $rowInnerJoin['DatePosted']
                        )
                    );
```

Comment: your console shows "Cannot read property 'create' of undefined". Can u post what JS code are you using

Comment: ohh. sorry its just a google chrome extension error.. please ignore that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is that you only have one DateField for each of WorkOrders, maybe you should add `[]` in you array construction:

```
$ListOfWorkOrderDates[$rowInnerJoin['WorkOrder']][]=array(
    $rowInnerJoin['DateField'] => array
    (
        'DatePosted' => $rowInnerJoin['DatePosted']
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks mate! it work! I just tweak a bit of code.. here: 
`$ListOfWorkOrderDates[$rowInnerJoin['WorkOrder']][$rowInnerJoin['DateField']]=array('DatePosted' => $rowInnerJoin['DatePosted']);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 if (!isset($ListOfWorkOrderDates[$rowInnerJoin['WorkOrder']])) {
      $ListOfWorkOrderDates[$rowInnerJoin['WorkOrder']]=array();
 }
$ListOfWorkOrderDates[$rowInnerJoin['WorkOrder']][$rowInnerJoin['DateField']] = array
                    (
                    'DatePosted' => $rowInnerJoin['DatePosted']
                    );
```

What is happening in your code is that you are setting "Due Date" against "Workorder" and then replacing the same value against "Received". So in each case you are only getting "Received". What I have done is separated the initialization of array and setting of values in it.

Comment: it didn't work mate. it gives me `INternal Server Error`

Comment: sorry, i have corrected it, please check again,

Comment: this one work's too.. but i prefer the answer of @lpg. thanks mate! but dont worry i upvote yours too.